# Searching for a way to autofilter strings on an integer column

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using the devexpress gridview for an vehicle management program and got a column which shows if the data of this row is marked as deleted or not. In the database they are marked with "1" for active and "11" for deleted, so I've created an enum class:

```
public enum enmSystemstatus
{
    Created = 1, 
    Deleted = 11
}
```

and this event to mark them with an word instead of a number in the gridview:

```
private void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column == colVehicle_Systemstatus && e.Value != null)
        {
            e.DisplayText = (int)e.Value == (int)enmSystemstatus.Created ? "Active" : "Deleted";
        }
    }
```

But the program should also be possible to use the autofilter row but if I enter a letter in the searchbox for the systemstatus column the program crashes because it is not possible to convert these values the exception is called:

> "system.invalidcastexception specified cast is not valid."

This is probably because the column on the database is an integer column but changing it to varchar doesn't affect something

Has anybody a solution for this?

thanks in advance

Comment: please post the exception message here, and the `enum` declaration of `enmSystemstatus`. what data type has the column in the datatable ? `int` ? or `varchar` ?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: "because the column on the database is an integer column" if the column is integer than the cast would be valid. Please verify that the column is not `varchar` or alike. can you post the entire exception message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress components(e.g. [GridControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3455/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid)) supports [the wide range of annotation attributes](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/18273/Common-Features/Data-Binding/Data-Annotation-Attributes) which allows you to effectively map integer values from the database onto the specific enumeration members and also provide meaningful and localizable descriptions for each enumeration members:

```
public enum DisplayStatus {
    [Display(Name = "ACTIVE")]
    Active= 1,
    [Display(Name = "DELETED")]
    Deleted = 11
}
public class Vehicle_DTO {
    [EnumDataType(typeof(DisplayStatus))]
    [Display(Name = "STATUS")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
// ...
gridControl1.DataSource = new List<Vehicle_DTO> {
    new Vehicle_DTO() { Status = 1 },
    new Vehicle_DTO() { Status = 11 },
    new Vehicle_DTO() { Status = 11 },
};
```

This customization will be applied to all UI elements including filters **without any event-handling** and errors:
[image: annotation attributes in action]